# Desktop icons position lost after logout / reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, desktop, reboot

**Environment**

Debian (Raspbian) distro (64-bit) on either 8GB Raspberry Pi 4, or Raspberry Pi Desktop (32-bit) on HP x86 laptop. Fully updated with apt.

**Problem**

After reboot or logout/login from the desktop GUI, all icons are shifted to the top left of the first screen. Also, the custom background image *on the first HDMI screen* is replaced by the default `clouds.jpg`. On early releases of bullseye, the problem wasn't there.

**Questions**

1. Anybody else seen this?
2. Where does bullseye store the desktop icon locations?

Comment: ok. strike that first question.
pi@raspi4 ~ $ uname -a

Linux raspi4 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 **aarch64** GNU/Linux

Comment: please edit the question ... info should not be added to comments

Comment: I'm outta here. Enough hoops to jump through in my life already. If you do not know the answer, don't bother to replt.